# How to do an effective Arangodb search which has 1,000 nodes' hop[1..1] and then merge all into one graph?

Tags: arangodb, aql

I'm getting stuck in such a problem now,
I'd like to run 1,000 AQLs, each of them does a one node hop[1..1] search with a filter[in the rest 999 nodeIds]. And then I need to merge all 1,000 graphs into one result. Timeout issues(60s) always come along. Is there an effective way to do it in just few seconds?

I tried to remove filters, but it doesn't help much and need more effort in the merge action.

Each AQL string is just like below,
"WITH company, people
FOR v, e, p IN 1..1 direction id0 GRAPH graph 
FILTER v._id IN [id1, id2, ..., id999]
LIMIT 1000 RETURN p;"

Comment: Is there a reason that you are using a graph database, if your depth is just 1? In a normal relational database that would be a foreign key. You can use foreign keys with ArangoDB if you want, you're not forced to use the graph features.

Comment: Billy, I think we need  more details on what you are trying to do to help you effectively, but as @DavisThomas Indicates ArangoDB is a multi-model DB and as such there is usually more that one way to solve a problem. In your case, it might be easier to just join different tables using plan AQL rather than trying to us the graph object. You could do something like : For c in company For w in worksAt Filter w._from = c._id  For e in people Filter e._id = w._to AND e._id in [id1,id,2,,,] Limit 1000 Return {...}   Or something like that